# Use jQuery to sort divs bases on text details

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, grails

I have multiple divs with the same class

```
<div class="row clearfix">
  <div class="col-md-5" >
      <div class='form-group employe-detail'>
          <input type="hidden" name="user[${i}].userId" value="${member?.user?.id }">
<p>
   <span class="employe-name" >${member?.user?.lastname}, ${member?.user?.firstname}</span>
    <span  class="employe-post" >${member?.jobTitle } </span>
<p>
      </div>
             </div>
   <div class="col-md-2">
                <div class='form-group employe-admin-contactP mb-5'>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="readymade-checkbox radio contact" name="user[${i}].isContact" id="contact-${member?.user?.id }"
                        <g:if test="${member?.isContactPerson()}">
                            checked
                        </g:if>
                    />
                    <label for="contact-${member?.user?.id }"  class="readymade-label"></label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

When the user click on some icon the "row clearfix" divs should be sort Ascending and Descending by the user  last name in class="employe-name".

How should I do the sorting and display the divs?

Comment: Can you post the HTML as served please, not with placeholders?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sarit8/a3o7q873/1/

Comment: May be this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hibbard_eu/C2heg/) can helps you.

Comment: @user1690588 your demo clearly works but I can't find any evidence in the jQuery documentation of  a `.sort()` method.

Comment: Have a look to this doc - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp . And this fiddle is not created by me, I just googled and got this.

Answer (score 0):

code will be something like this (didn't executed)

```
$('.someiconclass').click(function(){
    // sort first 
    var lnames = [];
    $('.row').each(function(){
        lnames.push[$(this).find('.employe-name').html().split(',')[0]];
    });
    lnames.sort();

    // arrange accordingly
    var alldivs = $('#parentId').clone(true);
    $('#parentId').empty();

    for(var i=0; i<lnames.length;i++){
       var rowdiv = $('.row').filter(function(ele){ return $(ele).find('.employe-name').html().split(',')[0] == lnames[i]; });
       $('#parentId').append(rowdiv);
    }
});
```

Comment: This is very laboured and needs some serious debugging.